# ld: unknown option: -melf_x86_64 while compiling shared ATLAS libraries on MacOS

Tags: macos, unix, ld, blas, atlas

I'm trying to install the ATLAS BLAS libraries [using this guide](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/atlas_install/atlas_install.html#SECTION00043000000000000000).  I have the static libraries working, but it's important that I have position independent libraries as well.  I get to the point in the guide where I'm supposed to issue `make shared` to get the shared libraries and I get the following error:

```
$ make shared
rm -f libatlas.so liblapack.so
make libatlas.so liblapack.so libf77blas.so libcblas.so liblapack.so
ld -melf_x86_64 -shared -soname libatlas.so -o libatlas.so \
        --whole-archive libatlas.a --no-whole-archive -lc -lpthread -lm
ld: unknown option: -melf_x86_64
make[1]: *** [libatlas.so] Error 1
make: *** [shared] Error 2
```

I've gone through the errata for ATLAS, but this issue doesn't seem to be addressed.  I'd appreciate advice on what direction to head.

--Andrew

Comment: What toolchain (and version) are you using?

Comment: OS X is a "non-elf" platform, so it is not surprising that the linker doesn't understand an elf specific option. I can only guess that your configuration is wrong somewhere and is using gnu/linux specific options when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ld -melf_x86_64 -shared -soname libatlas.so -o libatlas.so 
>           --whole-archive libatlas.a --no-whole-archive -lc -lpthread -lm

This Makefile is

1. Bogus: one should *almost* never link anything directly with `ld`
2. Written with assumption that it is using GNU-ld on ELF `x86_64` platform (incorrect in your case).

You need to adjust these instructions for your platform. Use appropriate commands to build a MacOS shared library (I don't know what they are, but I am sure you can use a search engine and/or `man ld` to find out).